# Why http to https redirection did not work with safari browser?

Tags: ios, http, https, safari

I am trying to load few of my websites in safari browser in mobile. When I explicitly run http urls in the browsers to see if it's been redirected to https url. I've tried different browsers in both IOS and android. But in safari browser the http url is not being redirected to https. I've tried with incognito and newly installed browser too.
Can anyone explain why this happens? Thanks in advance.